# Limit output to latest records, how?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Conceptual question:
I have a service in the background that outputs me from time to time some objects, so I want to show the user the output in a GUI. Which control should I use? Listview, since one line per processed item would fine, or Textbox output?

Where should I keep the objects from the service? In a Queue? But how can I easily bind it to the control so the oldest get removed (FIFO)? Any elegant idea how to best implement this?

Comment: Given the limited info, I don't see how any choice is any less arbitrary than the next.  Voting to close.

Comment: Rather than close this, @Rolf, pull some things out of concept: how is the Service sending the Objects to the UI program (a direct cross thread communication, a file, a database, etc.), is it just string data you are using, etc.?

Comment: Well, I think I will run a BackGroundWorkerThread (or other thread) that listens to Notifications from the db. This will do some work on the changes. From the processed data I will create a notification object with some fields like date, status and some text. This notification object finally with be displayed on the GUI (one string, a couple columns, not sure yet), I think Invoke will do this. The main thing I constantly get notifications, but I want just show the latest notifications (FIFO) and bound to control, everything else is in the log. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add my solution which works nicely:

```
public class SlidingBuffer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
private readonly Queue<T> _queue;

public int QueueMax { get; private set; }

public SlidingBuffer(int maxCount)
{
    QueueMax = maxCount;
    _queue = new Queue<T>(maxCount);
}

public void Add(T item)
{
    if (_queue.Count >= QueueMax)
    {
        _queue.Dequeue();
    }
    _queue.Enqueue(item);
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _queue.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
}
```

And the class with the items

```
public class SlidingItem
{
public SlidingItem(string text, int number)
{
    Text = text;
    Number = number;
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    Id = ++ItemsProcessed;
}

private static int _itemsProcessed;

public int ItemsProcessed
{
    get { return _itemsProcessed; }
    set { _itemsProcessed = value; }
}

public int Id { get; set; }

public string Text { get; set; }

public int Number { get; set; }

public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

public string ShowMembers()
{
    return string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", TimeStamp.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Number, Text, Id);
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return ShowMembers();
}
}
```

And finally bound to a ListBox:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = _controller.SlidingBuffer;
listBoxOutput.DataSource = bindingSource;
listBoxOutput.DisplayMember = "ShowMembers";
```